# Are there best practices for extensible magic methods in python?

Tags: python, magic-methods

Say I have built a library containing a `Foo` class, with support for some magic methods, say `__add__()` and `__radd__()`:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     def __add__(self, rhs):
...         print("Foo.__add__", rhs)
...     def __radd__(self, lhs):
...         print("Foo.__radd__", lhs)
... 
>>> foo = Foo()
>>> foo + 3
Foo.__add__ 3
>>> 3 + foo
Foo.__radd__ 3
```

When computing `3 + foo`, python first calls `type(3).__add__(3, foo)`, but as this returns `NotImplemented`, it falls back to `type(foo).__radd__(foo, 3)`:

```
>>> type(3).__add__(3, foo)
NotImplemented
```

I would like developers to be able to build libraries on top of my library, say a library containing a class `Bar`, and I want them to have full control. In particular, I want to implement some mechanism that lets the other library decide whether `foo + bar` should call `foo.__add__(bar)` or `bar.__radd__(foo)`.

I see that NumPy solved this using the `__array_priority__` scheme. But this seems to cause some headaches (considering the number of questions and issues opened about this). Are there other best practices?

Comment: Do you want this to work with existing classes, too?

Comment: Although your question is quite interesting, it lacks details. Can you descrbe more aspects of desired behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

One popular option is to maintain a list of types supported by the LHS, and if the RHS's type is not in the list, then return `NotImplemented`:

```
class Foo(object):
    SUPPORTED_TYPES = (int, Foo)
    def __add__(self, rhs):
        if isinstance(type(rhs), SUPPORTED_TYPES):
            [...] # compute self + rhs
        else:
            return NotImplemented
```

This works well unless `rhs` is a smart subtype of one of the `SUPPORTED_TYPES`: there is no way it will get control.
Moreover, listing types this way is not very flexible. It might be better to rely on duck typing than on a list of hard coded types.

Answer (score 1):

A simple option is to try to let the LHS do whatever it needs to do (in the example below it calls the RHS's `value()` method) and in case it raises an exception, catch it and return `NotImplemented`:

```
class Foo(object):
    [...]
    def __add__(self, rhs):
        try:
            return self._value + rhs.value()
        except AttributeError:
            return NotImplemented
```

Simple as can be, no need to maintain a list of `SUPPORTED_TYPES`. However, there is a risk that the RHS implements a `value()` method that has nothing to do with this task, so it might be a bit risky. Moreover, there is no easy way for the `rhs` to get full control over the result.

In Python, it's usually better to beg for forgiveness rather than to ask for permission, as above, but you may prefer to check that the `rhs` has the `value()` method:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __add__(self, rhs):
        rhs_value_func = getattr(rhs, "value", None)
        if rhs_value_func is None:
            return NotImplemented
        else:
            return self._value + rhs_value_func()
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another option is to use an attribute such as `__foo_priority__`, somewhat like NumPy does with its `__array_priority__`:

```
class Foo(object):
    __foo_priority__ = 0
    def __add__(self, rhs):
        delegate = True
        try:
            rhs_prio = type(rhs).__foo_priority__
            delegate = (self.__foo_priority__ < rhs_prio)
        except AttributeError:
            delegate = True
        if delegate:
            return NotImplemented
        else:
            return self.value_ + rhs.value()
```

This option is slightly more complicated, but pretty flexible. The only (minor) issue with this option is that it requires the `rhs`'s type to have an extra attribute, so there's no way to give control to the `rhs` if it is an existing type without this attribute.